# Why is array indexing symmetric in index and name

Tags: c++, arrays

Looking at some weird obfuscation contest code today I realized that array indexing is symmetric, in other words, `x[n]` is the same as `n[x]`. For example, consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::cout << x[3] << ' ' << 3[x]; // both display 3
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb61a9f987bf4e87)

Is this indeed standard compliant, and if yes, is there any good reason why? And a bonus if you can provide a standard reference/quote.

PS: the code compiles fine with both gcc and clang

Comment: This is a dupe.  searching...

Comment: @NathanOliver Please close it if you find it, I was almost sure that there should be another question like it, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Thanks @firststep.  Added to my favorites now.

Comment: That's indeed a good find! Although it should probably be also tagged as C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver No problem. (cc vsoftco) A user couple days back asked the same question.

Comment: @FirstStep Learning something new everyday here :)

Comment: @NathanOliver I've done the same now, though _@vsoftco's_  question title sounds way better.

Comment: That is why we need to keep it.  It should be a good sign post.

Comment: @NathanOliver _Upvoting_ always marks good dupe sign posts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that in C (and C++) both expressions are equal to `*(x + 3)` == `*(3 + x)`.

Comment: With pointers yes, but I see `[ ]` more like an operator (although it's clearly not for PODs).

Comment: C-style arrays decay to pointers in many contexts. This is one of these I believe.